# Overriding function "it" in WDIO

Tags: testing, webdriver-io, wdio

I want to override a function "it". I can do it?

```
old_it = it
it = (name, foo) ->
  console.log('111')
  old_it(name, foo)
  console.log('222')
```

When I run this code, a message is output to the console that "it = undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct the properties **beforeTest** and **afterTest** in the file wdio.conf.js

```
...
    beforeTest: function (test, context) {
        console.log('start test ' + test.title)
    },
...

    afterTest: function(test, context, { error, result, duration, passed, retries }) {
        console.log('finish test ' + test.title)
    },
...
```